# How to Convert C# code to Java. BigInteger.ModPow

Tags: java, c#, encoding

How can I convert this C# code to Java?

```
var signature = Convert.ToBase64String(BigInteger.ModPow(aToEncode, bToEncode, cToEncode).ToByteArray(false, true));
```

My problem that `BigInteger` in Java hasn't a `modPow` method with three parameters, so I dont understand how to write similar code in Java

Comment: It looks like the Java version is an instance method, but in C# it's static. They are equivalent, just called slightly differently. It might help to look up some examples for each. Should be pretty clear after seeing how each language uses it.

Comment: I think the Java method is a instance method so you call it on the value you want to preform the power and mod on vs C# where you pass all 3 values to a static method.

Comment: You don't need 3 parameters in Java's method. Check out this page for examples calling it on a `BigInteger` instance: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/biginteger-modpow-method-in-java/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is there. In a different way, you need to do.

```
BigInteger biginteger1, biginteger2, res; 
  
        biginteger1 = new BigInteger("123455"); 
        biginteger2 = new BigInteger("234556"); 
        BigInteger exp = new BigInteger("10"); 
  
        res = biginteger1.modPow(exp, biginteger2);
byte[] resBytes = BigInteger.valueOf(res).toByteArray(); 
String signature = new String(Base64.getEncoder().encode(resBytes));
```